# How do I get ServiceStack's x csharp to generate dto's for only a specific type

Tags: servicestack

I'm using the ServiceStack `x` tool with the `csharp` option to generate a C# dtos.cs file.  On first create it works great.  I've used its generated content to move DTO's to dto-specific files, and applied modifications to them.

Now I want to update it after adding a new class to my `ServiceModel` project.  So I edit the settings in the existing file, by uncommenting the `IncludeTypes` option, like so:

```
...
//ExportValueTypes: False
IncludeTypes: TenantConfig
//ExcludeTypes: 
...
```

Then when I run `x csharp`, the file is updated, but it now contains ONLY the type class for TenantConfig.  It does not include all the DTOs (CreateTenantConfig, UpdateTenantConfig, etc).

How can I get the `x csharp` tool to generate the missing DTOs when including a specific type?

As an aside, I took the other approach of using the `ExcludeTypes` instead of `IncludeTypes`, and listed all the first-time-generated types to be excluded.  But this time it generated all the DTOs, even for the excluded types (and my new TenantConfig type), but the only difference is that it did not generate their actual type classes in the `.Types` namespace.  Which seems odd.  I would think that DTOs for `ExcludedTypes` should NOT be generated?  Perhaps I am missing some documentation (though I have searched) regarding the use of this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the various options for including types in the [C# Add ServiceStack Reference](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-add-servicestack-reference#includetypes) docs, e.g. to include a Request DTO and all it's referenced types you can use:

```
IncludeTypes: TenantConfig.*
```

Comment: mmm looks like I was a bit quick in marking this as the answer? I've just tried it now after adding a new table to my database called `RolePermission`, and confirming that the endpoints are available via AutoQuery. Now I want to generate the classes, and I have `IncludeTypes: RolePermission.*` in my existing `dtos.cs` file, and an execution of `x csharp` regenerates the existing file with only the `RolePermission` Type, without any of the DTO classes.  There seems to be no difference between `IncludeTypes: RolePermission.*` and `IncludeTypes: RolePermission`. They both output the same thing.

Comment: `.*` is for including referenced types in a Request DTO, Is `RolePermission` a **Request DTO**?

Comment: Ah no, RolePermission is the Type representation of the AutoQuery-aware database table that I added...but your answer has lead me on a new path.  The following approach worked: `IncludeTypes: CreateRolePermission,PatchRolePermission,QueryRolePermissions,DeleteRolePermission,UpdateRolePermission`.  This generated the DTOs that I needed.  I was (mistakenly) of the impression that the earlier attempt using `RolePermission.*`  would generate the type and all its DTOs.

Comment: So I'll mark this as the answer, even though technically as written it did not give me the result I needed, it lead me to the correct outcome.  Thanks.